# Python список дат

Tags: python, datetime

Есть дата например 31.12.2021. Как на основе неë в Python получить список из 10 предыдущих и 10 следующих дат-концов квартала?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37153231/4804629 - вычитаете 3 месяца, вызываете функцию. и так в цикле...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов - использовать [`pandas.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.date_range(end='31.12.2021', periods=10, freq='Q', closed='left').to_series(),
                pd.date_range(start='31.12.2021', periods=10, freq='Q').to_series()])
print(df)
```

```
2019-09-30   2019-09-30
2019-12-31   2019-12-31
2020-03-31   2020-03-31
2020-06-30   2020-06-30
2020-09-30   2020-09-30
2020-12-31   2020-12-31
2021-03-31   2021-03-31
2021-06-30   2021-06-30
2021-09-30   2021-09-30
2021-12-31   2021-12-31
2022-03-31   2022-03-31
2022-06-30   2022-06-30
2022-09-30   2022-09-30
2022-12-31   2022-12-31
2023-03-31   2023-03-31
2023-06-30   2023-06-30
2023-09-30   2023-09-30
2023-12-31   2023-12-31
2024-03-31   2024-03-31
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```